# Apache POI Excel: Multiple Data Validation in same column

Tags: excel, apache, validation, apache-poi

I am using Poi version 3.16. I am writing code in Groovy.
I try to add 2 different data validation in the same column. The first is accepted but the second failed. Anybody has an idea to do right? Thanks a lot so far.

```
// Something like that
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("pois-test.xls");
def workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
def sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");

 // Create 2 Dropdownlists
addMyValidation(1, 10, 3, 3, new String[]{"One", "Two", "Three"});
addMyValidation(15, 25, 3, 3, new String[]{"A", "B", "C"});   // second one failed without errormessage

Boolean addMyValidation(int firstRow, int lastRow, int firstCol, int lastCol, String[] listOfValue)
{
        def helper     = new XSSFDataValidationHelper(sheet);
        def constraint = helper.createExplicitListConstraint(listOfValue);
        CellRangeAddressList range = new CellRangeAddressList(firstRow, lastRow, firstCol, lastCol);
        def validation = helper.createValidation(constraint, range);

        validation.setErrorStyle(ErrorStyle.STOP);
        validation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(true);
        validation.setEmptyCellAllowed(false);
        validation.setShowPromptBox(true);
        validation.setShowErrorBox(true);

        sheet.addValidationData(validation);

        return (true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Works for me using `Java`and `apache poi`. Should also work using your `Groovy` code though.

May be you are not entirely sure where row 15 actually is since row id's  and column id's both are 0 based?

The following complete code works:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddressList;

public class CreateExcelDataValidation {

 static Sheet sheet = null;

 static boolean addMyValidation(int firstRow, int lastRow, int firstCol, int lastCol, String[] listOfValue) {
  DataValidationHelper helper = sheet.getDataValidationHelper();
  DataValidationConstraint constraint = helper.createExplicitListConstraint(listOfValue);
  CellRangeAddressList range = new CellRangeAddressList(firstRow, lastRow, firstCol, lastCol);
  DataValidation validation = helper.createValidation(constraint, range);

  validation.setErrorStyle(DataValidation.ErrorStyle.STOP);
  validation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(true);
  validation.setEmptyCellAllowed(false);
  validation.setShowPromptBox(true);
  validation.setShowErrorBox(true);

  sheet.addValidationData(validation);

  return true;
 }        

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
  sheet = workbook.createSheet("Data Validation");

  sheet.createRow(0).createCell(3).setCellValue("Col 3");
  sheet.createRow(1).createCell(0).setCellValue("Row 1");
  sheet.createRow(10).createCell(0).setCellValue("Row 10");
  sheet.createRow(15).createCell(0).setCellValue("Row 15");
  sheet.createRow(25).createCell(0).setCellValue("Row 25");

  addMyValidation(1, 10, 3, 3, new String[]{"One", "Two", "Three"});
  addMyValidation(15, 25, 3, 3, new String[]{"A", "B", "C"});

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelDataValidation.xlsx");
  workbook.write(out);
  workbook.close();
  out.close();

 }

}
```

Comment: Hi Axel. Wow. You are unbelievable fast!!! Thanks a lot. And you are right. The error was at another place. And I've found it by using your code.